# Microsoft #include header file (.h) for "_HFILE"

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to compile some Microsoft SAPI example code in a non-Microsoft C++ Compiler, and am getting an error at this line:

```
    _HFILE m_hfilePrev;
```

Presumably because it doesn't recognize the _HFILE #define.  Does anybody know what .h file I should include for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in `crtdbg.h`

```
typedef void *_HFILE; /* file handle pointer */
```